# date time issue moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

sometimes my timestamp is more than 10 digits. I am using moment js
function is:

```
moment.unix(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

when it is 10 digits long giving me perfect answer. but when more than 10 digits. don't know why it is giving my wrong year.

sample:
correct: 1433167001 gives me 2015-06-01 13:56 
Incorrect: 1433287744646  gives me date: 47389-01-29 12:37

I also tried /1000 not working

**code**

```
 - var timestamp =''
                                - if (typeof(res[j]['timestamp']) !== 'undefined'){
                                    - timestamp = Math.floor(res[j]['timestamp']);
                                    - if (timestamp.length > 10) {
                                        - timestamp = Math.floor(timestamp/1000)
                                    - }
                                -}

                                tr
                                    td #{index++}
                                    td #{results[i]['userInfo']['username']}
                                    td #{typeName}
                                    td #{value}
                                    td #{moment.unix(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}
```

The above code is in jade.

Comment: What exactly did you divide by 1000? If it's `timestamp`, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, the term "Unix Timestamp" refers to the number of *seconds* that have elapsed since midnight, January 1st 1970 UTC (not counting leap seconds).

```
var m = moment.unix(numberOfSeconds);
```

However, JavaScript and many other platforms define their timestamps in terms of *milliseconds* instead of seconds.

```
var m = moment(numberOfMilliseconds);
```

It is important that you understand the source of your data to know whether the timestamps are in terms of seconds or milliseconds.  If you guess based upon the number of digits, then you are excluding a range of possible values.